# How to concate string outside loop using map() method in jsx?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

according my code bellow how to correct way to append string outside loop when using `map()` method

this is my incorrect way when I try to concate `<table><th>Emploeye Name</th><th>Salary</th></table>` tag before and after call `map()` method

```
buildString(data){
  return(//start return
  <table class="table">
   <th>Emploeye Name</th><th>Salary</th>
  data.map((employeye) =>            
        
        <tr>
          <td>{employeye.employee_name}</td>
          <td>{employeye.employee_salary}</td>
        </tr>           
          )
     </table>  
); //end return  

}
```

for this mistake I get this message

```
./src/views/emploeyes/Employeyes.js
  Line 27:20:  'employeye' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 28:20:  'employeye' is not defined  no-undef
```

and this is correct way without concate anything before `map()` method

```
buildString(data){
      return(
      data.map((employeye) =>           
            <tr>
              <td>{employeye.employee_name}</td>
              <td>{employeye.employee_salary}</td>
            </tr>
              )
      );      
  }
```

please helpme to fix that and explain me thank you.

Comment: You should wrap that `data.map...` in curly bracket `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JSX, you must use `{}` on your code

```
buildString(data){
  return(//start return
    <table className="table">
      <thead>
        <th>Emploeye Name</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {
        data.map((employeye) => (
          <tr>
            <td>{employeye.employee_name}</td>
            <td>{employeye.employee_salary}</td>
          </tr>           
        ))
      }
      </tbody>
   </table>  
  ); 
}
```

Comment: thank you @Kevin Li. by the way. why I need { } before map() method. but at the beginning of  return() statement not?

what is the purpose of double baracket "{}" tag in jsx?

Comment: I think you need to have more understanding about JSX. https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html

Comment: I did. Curly braces should be use when we make expression. That is the point what I get from yours refference above. Thank you